# Creating a list of lists using np.where() objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I am trying to create a list of lists in Python by using `np.where(pd.isnull(x))` to create the lists to be appended. Essentially what I am trying to do is loop through a data.frame, for each row finding which of the values are not null. I am using the `np.where()` because I want the indices of non-null values as an inner list, which then should be appended to an outer list. This outer list will then be reduced to only the unique values. My current idea is something along the lines of:

```
outer_list = []
outer_list.append(list(range(0, number_of_columns)) #This is the longest possible return,
#but it may not be found in the data frame
for i in list(range(0, len(data_frame.index))):
       row = data_frame.iloc[i,:].tolist()
       item = np.where(pd.notnull(row))[0] #using [0] to turn the array into a list 
       outer_list.append(item)
unique_list = np.unique(outer_list)
```

However, when I try this `item` reverts back to an array(?) object, e.g. `array([5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int64)` when appended, which I don't want. It is vital that the `outer_list` contains a series of lists. How can I circumvent this / how should I be doing this?

I'm sure that this not the best way of solving this problem, so any suggestions on how to improve would also be greatly appreciated, I am quite new to Python.

The Data looks something like this:

I didn't know how to best make a table...

[image]

Like above, the code would take the indices of the non null values and generate a list of lists, starting with the longest possible list, (which would be added outside the loop).

```
outer_list = []
outer_list.append([0,1,2,3,4])
```

Then go through the rows of the table adding the following list for each row respectively:

```
[0,1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4]
[2,3,4]
[0,1,2,3]
```

which would all be appended to the `outer_list` to give the following result:

```
[[0,1,2,3,4], [0,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [0,1,2,3]]
```

which would then be reduced down to a unique list:

```
[[0,1,2,3,4], [0,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [2,3,4]]
```

As element 1 and 4 are the same.

Comment: can you show your sample data and intended output ? probably easier just to use native pandas function for this.

Comment: `np.where` returns a tuple of arrays, one array per dimension.  `np.where(cond)[0]` just extracts the array from the tuple.  `np.where(cond)[0].tolist()` would convert the array to a list.  But I'm not sure that helps with the `np.unique` step.

Comment: @hpaulj This worked exactly as I wanted. Thank you.